# Navigation bar translucent property misplaces other UIComponents?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am facing a issue when I set the translucent property of navigation bar to **NO**, other UIComponents such as buttons and UIViews do not show up in proper place.What must be the reason?

So I have to use this:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Instead of what I require is this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iOS 7 navigation bar issue. You can try to add this code to wiewDidLoad in your View Controller

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

It helped me to solve my issue